# Framework for JMeter

Tags: frameworks, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I recently started learning JMeter for doing performance testing our application.
I have a testplan (.jmx) and run it periodically by using Jenkins + Ant.
It is good so far.

My question is - we have a Keyword driven framework, TestNG ..etc for functional testing tools QTP, Selenium.

So, do we have any framework like that for JMeter?
Or what is your framework?
How do you maintain your JMeter test plan?

Any inputs will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you may be interested in [Ruby-JMeter](http://flood-io.github.io/ruby-jmeter/) project - Ruby-based DSL for building JMeter test plans (+ link to [project on github](https://github.com/flood-io/ruby-jmeter)).

As well you can use Maven as alternative to Ant to run your automated JMeter tests:

- [JMeter Maven Plugin](http://jmeter.lazerycode.com/)
- JMeterMavenPlugin on [JMeter Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterMavenPlugin)
- JMeterMavenPlugin on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jmeter-maven-plugin)
- [Automated Performance Testing with JMeter and Maven](http://www.slideshare.net/PerconaPerformance/automated-performance-testing-with-j-meter-and-maven)