# Can anyone help me to create Jmeter Framework?

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

any plugin/add-on which can help to create Framework? 
From where to start creating framework and how to proceed?

Your input is valuable.

Thanks,
Ami

Comment: This question will be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572637/framework-for-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

I had a same question when I started learning JMeter. I did not really find any good answer.

I think below links might help you.

**JMeter + Ant + Jenkins integration:**

This has the details on running parameterized tests from Jenkins, creating reports, emailing the results. It also has a sample project which you can download and modify as per your needs.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-continuous-performance-testing-part1/
http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-continuous-performance-testing-part2/

**JMeter + InfluxDB + Grafana Integration:**

Getting real time results while jmeter is running the test.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-real-time-results-influxdb-grafana/

**Creating Reusable Test Scripts:**

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-modularizing-test-scripts/

**Executing specific thread group:**

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-manage-test-plan/